# Shortcut to queue a new build?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to queue a new build within **Visual Studio 2015**? I'm having to go to builds --> pick my build ---> queue new build hundreds of times today, and I am wondering how can I set up a keyboard shortcut that will queue that specific build for me? I'm referring specifically to a **TFS build.**

Comment: You could have it queue up a build any time you check something in.

Comment: that's a beautiful point. how do i do that?

Comment: Go to the build definition.  Choose Trigger.  There should be an option there to do Continuous Integration - Build each check-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot from chief7 is for vNext build which only support on TFS2015.

For TFS2013 and earlier version, you can find the option in Your Build Definition→ Trigger → Continuous Integration - Build each check-in
[image]

Moreover, suggest you to use **Gated Check-in build**-*accept check-ins only if the submitted changes merge and build successfully*. This is more suitable for your requirement. More info from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd794776.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the build to be trigger by each check-in on the Triggers tab of you Build Definition:

[image]